# Memory is not release audio player

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, automatic-ref-counting, avaudioplayer

In my application, i have used the audio player , Since when i click  the button repeatedly  , The memory is increased as and it goes. Here my code.

```
- (IBAction)didTapFlag:(id)sender
{
int btnTag = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;
NSLog(@"btnTag %d",btnTag);
checkBtnCondition=YES;
menuView.hidden=YES;

if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [self playPauseAudio];
}

NSLog(@"Check %c",iscommentOn);
NSLog(@"swipecount%d",swipeCount);

if( iscommentOn==NO)
{if (btnTag == 0)
{
    [mCommentView hide];
    // [mCommentView setHidden:YES];
    iscommentOn=YES;
    flagBtn.tag=1;
}
else
{
    [mCommentView setHidden:NO];
    [commentPlayer1 stop];
    iscommentOn=NO;
    commentPlayer1 = nil;
    flagBtn.tag = 0;
}
}
else
{
    iscommentOn=NO;


    if(![commentPlayer1 isPlaying])
    {
        iscommentOn=NO;
    }
    NSLog(@"->%c",iscommentOn);
    if(!iscommentOn)
    {
        iscommentOn=YES;
        if(mCommentView)
        {
            if (btnTag == 0)
            {
                [commentPlayer1 stop];
                commentPlayer1 = nil;
                [mCommentView hide];
                flagBtn.tag = 1;
            }
            return;
        }
        float comx;
        float comy;
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            comx = 200;
            comy = 280;
        }
        else
        {
            comx = 50;
            comy = 170;
        }
        mCommentView = [[CommentUtility alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(comx, comy, 330, 250)];
        [mCommentView setDelegate:(id)self];
        [self.view addSubview:mCommentView];


        switch (swipeCount) {
            case 1:
                showComment = 0;
                break;
            case 5:
                showComment = 1;
                break;
            case 11:
                showComment = 2;
                break;
            case 15:
                showComment = 3;
                break;
            case 19:
                showComment = 4;
                break;
            case 22:
                showComment = 5;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (language==1) {
            NSLog(@"English");

            [mCommentView setCommentText:[commenttextEngArray objectAtIndex:showComment]];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Hindi");

            [mCommentView setCommentText:[commenttextHinArray objectAtIndex:showComment]];

        }

        if (btnTag == 1)
        {
            [mCommentView show];
            iscommentOn=NO;
            flagBtn.tag = 0;
        }

        if(commentPlayer1)
            commentPlayer1 = nil;

        NSURL *url;
        if(swipeCount==1)
        {
            if (language==1) {
                NSLog(@"English");
                url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"kittur rani english" ofType:@"mp3"]];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Hindi");
                url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"raniChinamma" ofType:@"mp3"]];
            }
        }
        if(swipeCount==5)
        {
            if (language==1) {
                NSLog(@"English");
                url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AvantiBai English" ofType:@"mp3"]];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Hindi");
                url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"RaniAvantiBai" ofType:@"mp3"]];
            }
        }
        if(swipeCount==11)
        {
            if (language==1) {
                NSLog(@"English");
                url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Bikaji Cama English" ofType:@"mp3"]];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Hindi");
                url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BhikajiCama" ofType:@"mp3"]];
            }
        }
        if(swipeCount==15)
        {
            if (language==1) {
                NSLog(@"English");
                url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Begum of Avadh english" ofType:@"mp3"]];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Hindi");
                url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Begumhazrat" ofType:@"mp3"]];
            }
        }
        if(swipeCount==22)
        {
            if (language==1) {
                NSLog(@"English");
                url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"kasturba gandhi" ofType:@"mp3"]];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Hindi");
                url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"KasturbaGandhi" ofType:@"mp3"]];
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"url 3 %@", url);

        NSError *error;
        commentPlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        [commentPlayer1 setDelegate:(id)self];
        if(readMode != 2)
        {
            [commentPlayer1 setVolume:5.0f];
        }
        else{
            [commentPlayer1 setVolume:0.0f];
        }
        [commentPlayer1 prepareToPlay];
        [commentPlayer1 play];

    }
}

}
```

I have added the code find the memory usage

```
 -(void) logMemUsage {
// compute memory usage and log if different by >= 100k
int cacheSizeMemory = 16*1024*1024; // 16MB
int cacheSizeDisk = 32*1024*1024; // 32MB
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];


static long prevMemUsage = 0;
long curMemUsage = usedMemory();
long memUsageDiff = curMemUsage - prevMemUsage;

if (memUsageDiff > 100000 || memUsageDiff < -100000) {
    prevMemUsage = curMemUsage;
    NSLog(@"Memory used %7.1f (%+5.0f), free %7.1f kb", curMemUsage/1000.0f, memUsageDiff/1000.0f, freeMemory()/1000.0f);
}
}
```

Since it shows the log as

```
  2013-06-06 13:44:27.287 Jansirani[8716:707] Memory used 23396.4 (+1794), free 28647.4 kb
  2013-06-06 13:44:37.286 Jansirani[8716:707] Memory used 26214.4 (+2818), free 32739.3 kb
  2013-06-06 13:45:37.284 Jansirani[8716:707] Memory used 29466.6 (+1855), free 35049.5 kb
```

Is there any way release memory when audio stops?Please help me out

Comment: You can check these links.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352588/avaudioplayer-memory-leak

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221024/avaudioplayer-leaks

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932913/massive-avaudioplayer-memory-leaks

Comment: Profile your application with Instruments Memory Leaks. It will point you to the exact line that's leaking memory. Also, when asking a question about memory leakage, pl don't forget to mention if you're using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just leaking the AVAudioPlayer instance. A delegate holds a pointer to an object, but in general a delegate does not hold a retained reference. So, your code seem to allocate objects and then just leak them. In order to hold on to an object, code must use a property declaration and uses nonatomic and retain.